# wordpress- different users get different posts?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to build a plugin where logged in subscribers will get different posts. one subscriber will get (1-5 posts) and the other subscriber will get (6-10 posts) per day(24 hours limit) randomly. all the subscribers are getting the same posts for 24 hours now. any tips to get the solution.

```
public function define_shortcode() {
        add_shortcode('testcode',[$this,'ts']);
    }

public function ts($user_atts){
        $default_atts = [
            'ts-id' => false
        ];
        $atts = shortcode_atts($default_atts, $user_atts, 'testcode');

        //Check for transient. If none, then execute WP_Query
            if (empty( get_transient('job'))) {
                $lia = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_type' => 'post_link',
                    'posts_per_page' =>5,
                    'orderby' => 'rand',
                ));
                // Put the results in a transient. Expire after 5 seonds.
                set_transient( 'job', $lia, 60*60*24);
            } 

            $output= " ";
            // Run the loop as normal

            if ( $job= get_transient("job")) { 

            $output.="<div class=letter>";
            while ( $job->have_posts() ){ 
                $job->the_post(); 
                    // featured posts found, do stuff
                        $output.="<div class=test>";
                        $output.='<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">';
                        $output.= get_the_title();
                        $output.= get_the_content();
                        $output.='</a>';
                        $output.='<img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().'">;
                        $output.="</div>";
                    } 
            $output.="</div>";          
        }
  wp_reset_postdata();
  return $output;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried to achieve your goal? Note that people on SO will not code for you